# How to get the text input given by a user for an HTML page through python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How to get the text input given by a user for an HTML page through python?

e.g.

```
<html>
<input id="post_form_id" name="fooput" value="" />
</html>
```

Now, the user inputs the value abcxyz in the text field. How can I get that value using python? I already know how it is done through javascript but I want to do it using python.

Also, I already tried Beautiful Soup but it can only return the preset value of the field.
SO I can do

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(open("myhtmldoc.htm")) 
print soup.find('input')['value']
```

But this wil only give me the preset value and not the value given by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a script that is called when the form is submitted. Typically, you use some framework that takes care of the sundry details.

A lightweight framework like [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org) makes this task easy:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def print_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('form.html',result=request.form['fooput'])
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('form.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In your `form.html`:

```
{% if result %}
    You entered: {{ result }}
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" action=".">
   <input id="post_form_id" name="fooput" value="" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good documentation:http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/
Have a look.

EDIT:
a little bit faster to find:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#accessing-request-data